# Is it possible to connect FT2232D's 3V3OUT pin to VCCIO for USB-JTAG programming?

Tags: usb, programming, jtag, ftdi

I want to design a [USB-JTAG Programmer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/126367/ftdi-chip-ft2232d-malfunction) with FT2232D. And I want to program Xilinx spartan3 FPGA with it, so I need 3.3 volt logic for VCCIO. Datasheet indicates that FT2232D has an internal regulator to convert 5v to 3.3v:

*"It‟s prime purpose is to provide the internal 3.3V supply to the USB transceiver cell and the RSTOUT# pin. A small amount of current (<= 5mA) can be drawn from this pin to power external 3.3V logic if required."*

I don't know wheather I can connect this pin to VCCIO, and how much current is required for this purpose (programming).

Comment: So what does the Xilinx spartan3 datasheet say it's 3.3V current requirement is? The datasheet will specify that information.

Comment: You want to use level shifters - FPGAs use lower voltages and may not like JTAG signals at 3.3 Volts.

Answer (score 1):

According to the datasheet of a standart programmer, you need around 10mA. You can check it by yourself Here's [a link](http://www.xinpian.net/Xilinx/XCF/XCF01.pdf)!